# Php : How to get the id from the name

Tags: php

I have a table name manager and I have two fields manager_id,manager_name. I'am trying to get the manager_id from the manager_name. But it is not showing any result and error.

This is my code.

```
<?php
     $jdata = $_GET['js'];
     $result = json_decode($jdata,true);
     $name=$result['mname'];
     $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','projmanagement'); 
     $mid = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT manager_id FROM manager WHERE manager_name=".$name);
     echo $mid;
?>
```

I'am getting value if I print $name. But I can't get the value for $mid.

Comment: Try to `var_dump` $mid to see which results you get from the query!

Comment: @pbaldauf yes it is showing like this. object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` returns boolean ( `True` or `False` ) So it is normal PHP behavior.

```
php > a = False
php > print a
php >
```

You should update your query. Single quotes should be used for string values.

```
 $mid = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "SELECT manager_id FROM manager WHERE manager_name='".$name."'");
```

Comment: Oztas I'am getting 500 internal server error

Comment: @user3764346 You can check error log

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (name is a string , so put it inside single " ' " quotes)

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT manager_id FROM manager WHERE manager_name='$name'");
```

**Edit 2 [Debug] : Try this , see if mysql is connected**

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','projmanagement') or die('Error');
```

Comment: I'am getting 500 internal server error